How to get all messages post by person in team channels using power apps in teams
I have teams group in which there are multiple teams channel. I want to get all the post messages by any user and from those messages only want messages which contains "Open" as a string in first line of the message in combobox/Gallery to select by user.
I have tried using combobox MicrosoftTeams.GetMessagesFromChannel() function it was showing some id. I also tried with Gallery with some function and inside gallery I select layout as title and selected only body of the message. It was showing html text with message so I used HTMLText but now it is messed up all messages. I enable scrollbar but still it is not scrolling. I preferred Combobox to shows messages of user with string "Open". Can Anyone suggest me how Can I get messages properly.


1.First, you need to gather all the messages from the Teams channel. You can use the MicrosoftTeams.GetMessagesFromChannel() function to get the messages. 2.Then use a formula to filter the messages that contain "Open" in the first line. You can use the StartsWith function to check if the message starts with "Open".
3.Use a ComboBox to display the filtered messages. Set the Items property of the ComboBox to the filtered messages.

Thanks for response, how can I get message of specific member of the channel?

You can use the "Filter array" action to filter messages where the sender's email or name matches the specific member.

Thanks, I have updated question, in picture u can see I am using filter but messages are not coming message.

We tried below filter condition and got the results in the collection. https://i.sstatic.net/7AvjL9me.png

I think something wrong at my site. Now I am getting messages But, From the list of messages how to filter message which have "Open" in starting. As you said Startswith(text, "string on which i can filter"). but I have collection "ChannelMessages". how to filter to get text from there. Thanks

Got it. Thank you so much

1.First, you need to gather all the messages from the Teams channel. You can use the MicrosoftTeams.GetMessagesFromChannel() function to get the messages.
2.Then use a formula to filter the messages that contain "Open" in the first line. You can use the StartsWith function to check if the message starts with "Open".
3.You can use the "Filter array" action to filter messages where the sender's email or name matches the specific member (selected from combo box).

